# Protobuf-net object graph reference with surrogate

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

As far as I know, protobuf-net starting from v2 supports references but they cannot be used in conjunction with surrogate (exception *"A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization"* is thrown in this case)

I'm wondering if there is some workaround that I didn't consider to make it works.

Here following the code of my test case that reproduces the above exception.

Classes

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, GenderType gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum GenderType : byte
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Both = Male | Female
}

public class Family
{
    public Family(List<Person> people, Person familyHead = null)
    {
        People = people;

        FamilyHead = familyHead;
    }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Person FamilyHead { get; set; }
}

public class PersonSurrogate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Gender { get; set; }

    public PersonSurrogate(string name, byte gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
    }       

    #region Static Methods

    public static implicit operator Person(PersonSurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;

        return new Person(surrogate.Name, (GenderType)surrogate.Gender);

    }

    public static implicit operator PersonSurrogate(Person source)
    {
        return source == null ? null : new PersonSurrogate(source.Name, (byte)source.Gender);
    }

    #endregion       
}

public class FamilySurrogate
{
    public FamilySurrogate(List<Person> people, Person familyHead)
    {
        People = people;
        FamilyHead = familyHead;
    }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Person FamilyHead { get; set; }

    #region Static Methods

    public static implicit operator Family(FamilySurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;

        return new Family(surrogate.People, surrogate.FamilyHead);

    }

    public static implicit operator FamilySurrogate(Family source)
    {
        return source == null ? null : new FamilySurrogate(source.People, source.FamilyHead);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Serializer

```
/// <summary>
/// Class with model for protobuf serialization
/// </summary>
public class FamilySerializer
{    
    public GenderType GenderToInclude;

    public FamilySerializer(Family family, GenderType genderToInclude = GenderType.Both)
    {
        GenderToInclude = genderToInclude;
        Family = family;

        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
        FillModel();
        Model.CompileInPlace();         
    }

    public FamilySerializer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public Family Family { get; set; }
    public RuntimeTypeModel Model { get; protected set; }

    protected virtual void FillModel()
    {
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

        Model.Add(typeof(Family), false)
            .SetSurrogate(typeof(FamilySurrogate));

        MetaType mt = Model[typeof(FamilySurrogate)];
        mt.Add(1, "People");
        mt.AddField(2, "FamilyHead").AsReference = true;  // Exception "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization" - because using surrogate.
        mt.UseConstructor = false;

        Model.Add(typeof(Person), false)
            .SetSurrogate(typeof(PersonSurrogate));

        mt = Model[typeof(PersonSurrogate)]
            .Add(1, "Name")
            .Add(2, "Gender");
        mt.UseConstructor = false; // Avoids to use the parameterless constructor.
    }

    public void Save(string fileName)
    {            
        using (Stream s = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            Model.Serialize(s, Family, new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext(){Context = this});
        }
    }

    public void Open(string fileName)
    {
        using (Stream s = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Family = (Family)Model.Deserialize(s, null, typeof(Family), new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext(){Context = this});
        }
    }
}
```

Test Case

```
private Family FamilyTestCase(string fileName, bool save)
{           
    if (save)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Angus", GenderType.Male),
            new Person("John", GenderType.Male),
            new Person("Katrina", GenderType.Female),           
        };
        var fam = new Family(people, people[0]);

        var famSer = new FamilySerializer(fam);

        famSer.Save(fileName);

        return fam;
    }
    else
    {
        var famSer = new FamilySerializer();

        famSer.Open(fileName);

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(fam.People[0], fam.FamilyHead))
        {
            // I'd like this condition would be satisfied
        }

        return famSer.Family;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I understand that will be not a supported scenario, I found a way to handle this and I'd like to share my complete solution, in case someone else needs this (or if someone else wanted to share a better solution or improve my approach)

Classes

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, GenderType gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum GenderType : byte
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Both = Male | Female
}

public class Family
{
    public Family(List<Person> people, Person familyHead = null)
    {
        People = people;

        FamilyHead = familyHead;
    }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Person FamilyHead { get; set; }
}

#region Interfaces
/// <summary>
/// Interface for objects supporting the object graph reference.
/// </summary>
public interface ISurrogateWithReferenceId
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the id for the object referenced more than once during the process of serialization/deserialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Default value is -1.</remarks>
    int ReferenceId { get; set; }
}
#endregion

public class PersonSurrogate : ISurrogateWithReferenceId
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Standard constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public PersonSurrogate(string name, byte gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
        ReferenceId = -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private constructor for object graph reference handling.
    /// </summary>
    private PersonSurrogate(int referenceId)
    {
        ReferenceId = referenceId;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Gender { get; set; }

    #region object graph reference

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the unique id assigned to the surrogate during the process of serialization/deserialization to handle object graph reference.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Default value is -1.</remarks>
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj) || (ReferenceId > 0 && obj is ISurrogateWithReferenceId oi && oi.ReferenceId == ReferenceId);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (ReferenceId > 0)
            return ReferenceId;

        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion object graph reference

    protected virtual bool CheckSurrogateData(GenderType gender)
    {
        return gender == GenderType.Both || (GenderType)Gender == gender;
    }

    #region Static Methods  

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the surrogate to the related object during the deserialization process.
    /// </summary>        
    public static implicit operator Person(PersonSurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;

        if (FamilySerializer.GetCachedObject(surrogate) is Person obj)
            return obj;

        obj = new Person(surrogate.Name, (GenderType)surrogate.Gender);
        FamilySerializer.AddToCache(surrogate, obj);

        return obj;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the object to the related surrogate during the serialization process.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator PersonSurrogate(Person source)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;

        if (FamilySerializer.GetCachedObjectWithReferenceId(source) is PersonSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            surrogate = new PersonSurrogate(surrogate.ReferenceId);
        }
        else
        {
            surrogate = new PersonSurrogate(source.Name, (byte)source.Gender);
            FamilySerializer.AddToCache(source, surrogate);
        }

        return surrogate;
    }

    #endregion    
}

public class FamilySurrogate
{
    public FamilySurrogate(List<Person> people, Person familyHead)
    {
        People = people;
        FamilyHead = familyHead;
    }

    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Person FamilyHead { get; set; }

    #region Static Methods

    public static implicit operator Family(FamilySurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;

        return new Family(surrogate.People, surrogate.FamilyHead);

    }

    public static implicit operator FamilySurrogate(Family source)
    {
        return source == null ? null : new FamilySurrogate(source.People, source.FamilyHead);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Serializer

```
/// <summary>
/// Class with model for protobuf serialization
/// </summary>
public class FamilySerializer
{


    public GenderType GenderToInclude;

    public FamilySerializer(Family family, GenderType genderToInclude = GenderType.Both)
    {
        GenderToInclude = genderToInclude;
        Family = family;

        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
        FillModel();
        Model.CompileInPlace();        
    }

    public FamilySerializer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public Family Family { get; set; }
    public RuntimeTypeModel Model { get; protected set; }

    protected virtual void FillModel()
    {
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

        Model.Add(typeof(Family), false)
            .SetSurrogate(typeof(FamilySurrogate));

        MetaType mt = Model[typeof(FamilySurrogate)];
        mt.Add(1, "People"); // This is a list of Person of course
        //mt.AddField(2, "FamilyHead").AsReference = true;  // Exception "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization" - because using surrogate.            
        mt.Add(2, "FamilyHead");
        mt.UseConstructor = false;

        Model.Add(typeof(Person), false)
            .SetSurrogate(typeof(PersonSurrogate));

        mt = Model[typeof(PersonSurrogate)]
            .Add(1, "Name")
            .Add(2, "Gender")
            .Add(3, "ReferenceId");        
        mt.UseConstructor = false; // Avoids to use the parameter-less constructor.
    }

    #region Cache
    static FamilySerializer()
    {
        ResizeCache();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resizes the cache for object graph reference handling.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"></param>
    public static void ResizeCache(int size = 500)
    {
        if (_cache != null)
        {
            foreach (var pair in _cache)
            {
                pair.Value.ResetCache();
            }
        }

        _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, FamilySerializerCache>();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            _cache.TryAdd(i, new FamilySerializerCache());
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, FamilySerializerCache> _cache;

    /// <summary>
    /// For internal use only. Adds the specified key and value to the serializer cache for the current thread during the serialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objKey">The the element to add as key.</param>
    /// <param name="objValue">The value of the element to add.</param>
    /// <remarks>The <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId.ReferenceId"/> is updated for <see cref="objValue"/></remarks>
    public static void AddToCache(object objKey, ISurrogateWithReferenceId objValue)
    {
        _cache[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId].AddToCache(objKey, objValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For internal use only. Adds the specified key and value to the serializer cache for the current thread during the serialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objKey">The the element to add as key.</param>
    /// <param name="objValue">The value of the element to add.</param>
    /// <remarks>The <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId.ReferenceId"/> is updated for <see cref="objKey"/></remarks>
    public static void AddToCache(ISurrogateWithReferenceId objKey, object objValue)
    {
        _cache[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId].AddToCache(objKey, objValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For internal use only. Resets the cache for the current thread.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ResetCache()
    {
        _cache[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId].ResetCache();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For internal use only. Gets the <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> associated with the specified object for the current thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object corresponding to the value to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The related ISurrogateWithReferenceId if presents, otherwise null.</returns>
    public static ISurrogateWithReferenceId GetCachedObjectWithReferenceId(object obj)
    {
        return _cache[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId].GetCachedObjectWithReferenceId(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For internal use only. Gets the object associated with the specified <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="surrogateWithReferenceId">The <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> corresponding to the object to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The related object if presents, otherwise null.</returns>
    public static object GetCachedObject(ISurrogateWithReferenceId surrogateWithReferenceId)
    {
        return _cache[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId].GetCachedObject(surrogateWithReferenceId);
    }

    #endregion Cache

    public void Save(string fileName)
    {            
        using (Stream s = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            Model.Serialize(s, Family, new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext(){Context = this});
        }
    }

    public void Open(string fileName)
    {
        using (Stream s = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Family = (Family)Model.Deserialize(s, null, typeof(Family), new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext(){Context = this});
        }
    }
}
```

Serializer cache

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class to support object graph reference
/// </summary>
internal class FamilySerializerCache
{
    // weak table for serialization
    // ConditionalWeakTable uses ReferenceEquals() rather than GetHashCode() and Equals() methods to do equality checks, so I can use it as a cache during the writing process to overcome the issue with objects that have overridden the GetHashCode() and Equals() methods.
    private ConditionalWeakTable<object, ISurrogateWithReferenceId> _writingTable = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, ISurrogateWithReferenceId>();

    // dictionary for deserialization
    private readonly Dictionary<ISurrogateWithReferenceId, object> _readingDictionary = new Dictionary<ISurrogateWithReferenceId, object>();

    private int _referenceIdCounter = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value associated with the specified key during serialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the value to get.</param>
    /// <param name="value">When this method returns, contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the <paramref name="value" /> parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the internal dictionary contains an element with the specified key, otherwise False.</returns>
    private bool TryGetCachedObject(object key, out ISurrogateWithReferenceId value)
    {
        return  _writingTable.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value associated with the specified key during deserialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the value to get.</param>
    /// <param name="value">When this method returns, contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the <paramref name="value" /> parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the internal dictionary contains an element with the specified key, otherwise False.</returns>
    private bool TryGetCachedObject(ISurrogateWithReferenceId key, out object value)
    {
        return  _readingDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the internal dictionaries and the counter;
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetCache()
    {
        _referenceIdCounter = 1;
        _readingDictionary.Clear();

        // ConditionalWeakTable automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other references to a key exist outside the table, but I want to clean it as well.
        _writingTable = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, ISurrogateWithReferenceId>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified key and value to the internal dictionary during serialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to add.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add.</param>
    /// <remarks>If the object implements <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> interface then <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId.ReferenceId"/> is updated.</remarks>
    public void AddToCache(object key, ISurrogateWithReferenceId value)
    {
        if (value.ReferenceId == -1)
            value.ReferenceId = _referenceIdCounter++;

        _writingTable.Add(key, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified key and value to the internal dictionary during deserialization process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to add.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add.</param>
    /// <remarks>If the object implements <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> interface then <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId.ReferenceId"/> is updated.</remarks>
    public void AddToCache(ISurrogateWithReferenceId key, object value)
    {
        if (key.ReferenceId == -1)
            key.ReferenceId = _referenceIdCounter++;

        _readingDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> associated with the specified object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object corresponding to the value to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The related ISurrogateWithReferenceId if presents, otherwise null.</returns>
    public ISurrogateWithReferenceId GetCachedObjectWithReferenceId(object obj)
    {
        if (TryGetCachedObject(obj, out ISurrogateWithReferenceId value))
            return value;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object associated with the specified <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="surrogateWithReferenceId">The <see cref="ISurrogateWithReferenceId"/> corresponding to the object to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The related object if presents, otherwise null.</returns>
    public object GetCachedObject(ISurrogateWithReferenceId surrogateWithReferenceId)
    {
        if (TryGetCachedObject(surrogateWithReferenceId, out object value))
            return value;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Test Case

```
private Family FamilyTestCase(string fileName, bool save)
{           
    if (save)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Angus", GenderType.Male),
            new Person("John", GenderType.Male),
            new Person("Katrina", GenderType.Female),           
        };
        var fam = new Family(people, people[0]);

        var famSer = new FamilySerializer(fam);

        famSer.Save(fileName);

        return fam;
    }
    else
    {
        var famSer = new FamilySerializer();

        famSer.Open(fileName);

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(fam.People[0], fam.FamilyHead))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Family head is the same than People[0]!");
        }

        return famSer.Family;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for now this is just an unsupported scenario and I'm unaware of a way to make it magically work; it may be something that I can get back to at some point, but there are many much higher priority things that would take precedence.

My usual advice here - and this applies to any serializer, not just protobuf-net: any time you find yourself hitting a limitation of the serializer, or even just something that is *awkward to configure* in the serializer: stop fighting the serializer. This kind of problem almost always arises when people try to serialize their *regular domain model*, and something in the domain model isn't a perfect fit for their chosen serializer. Instead of trying arcane magic: **split your model** - have your *domain* model be a good fit for what you want your *application* to see, and create a **separate** model that is a great fit for your serializer. Then you don't need concepts like "surrogates". If you're using multiple serialization formats, or have multiple different "versions" of layout in the same serialization format: *have multiple serialization models*.

It really isn't worth the headache of trying to make on model serve multiple masters.

Comment: Hi @Marc, thanks for the quick reply. I need to use surrogate approach to handle versioning and I understand what you mean. if there will be some updates about this, please share a comment here :)

Comment: @ilCosmico if and when I update this, it will be in the medium-to-far future timescale; I won't remember this question number by then, sorry; you'll have to watch release notes

Comment: Hi @Marc, looking to the [release notes](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/releasenotes) I see no feature work planned for v2, that means I can wait for this in v3 only, am I right?

Comment: @ilCosmico you'll also see in the release notes that object tracking is a feature that is *not* currently implemented in v3, and I'm strongly leaning towards "don't implement it"; I haven't *fully* ruled it out; but it isn't an obvious "yes, we absolutely should do this" either